# Is there any purpose in the "inverting" potion?

Tags: prince-of-persia

In the classic Prince of Persia (1989), at level 9, there is a green potion that inverts the screen, making it harder to control the Prince.
Does it have any purpose other than increasing the difficulty on your first playthrough?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**No.** As per [Eizaz Azhar's FAQ](http://www.gamefaqs.com/pc/562672-prince-of-persia-1989/faqs/22642):

> {~ Reversal Potion~}
>
> Turns the whole screen upside down. Controls remain the same, it's only the point of
>   view that changes - turn your monitor upside down to get what I mean. Also comes in a
>   vase like a Life Extension Potion. To differentiate between these, again, look at the
>   bubbles. LEPs have RED bubbles, and other potions in vases have GREEN. To set the screen
>   back, you have to find and drink another Reversal Potion.
>
> First appearance : Level 9
>
> Found in         : Level 9
>
> Classification   : Joke

It serves no purpose other than to be fun/annoying/challenging. You can just turn your head/monitor and play upside down so it isn't even all that big a deal.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I've read that FAQ already, but I completely missed that description

Comment: Also, if you complete the level without drinking the 2nd potion, the screen reverts to normal (DOS version)